# Postgresql: View that gets total points for each unique user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: 'picks' and 'users':

```
Picks table
|id|user_id|points|

Users table
|id|name|
```

The below query definition is for a view named standings_view that pulls for these tables.

```
 SELECT picks.points,
    users.name
   FROM users
     JOIN picks ON users.id = picks.user_id;
```

The view currently shows:

```
|points|name |
|46    |casey|
|48    |casey|
|50    |dave |
|34    |dave |
```

I would like to show:

```
|points|name |
|94    |casey|
|84    |dave |
```

Any help for this is greatly appreciated. I am in over my head here

Comment: `group by name`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP

Comment: This is a basic `group by` query.  You should learn SQL basics if you want to use databases effectively.

Comment: thanks and @GordonLinoff - I was thrown into this mess and asked to get it working asap.  SQL is not my area of expertise, nor do I intend it to be.  Furthermore, your quip doesn't address the other half of my stupid question; the SUM part for the points.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - that link got me to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

After the view is created, query the view with

SELECT name, SUM(points) FROM standings_view GROUP BY name ORDER BY SUM (points) DESC;